# ContextualVersionConflict error message when using "from google.cloud import vision" on google colab

Tags: protocol-buffers, google-colaboratory, ocr

When I try to run `!pip install google-cloud-vision` and `from google.cloud import vision`on google colab

I get the following error:

> ContextualVersionConflict (protobuf 3.17.3 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5'), {'google-cloud-vision'})

I try several ways, it is not working

1. use !ls to check the protobuf in the colab path, it shows "protobuf-4.21.9.dist-info"
2. try to !pip install protobuf ==4.21.1
3. !gitclone the whole package of protobuf from github under the colab path of /content

I wonder if i am putting into a wrong route, or is there any thing else i can try to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm.... I'm not familiar with Google Collab but it appears the default `protobuf` version is out of date:

```bash
!pip freeze | grep protobuf
```

Yields:

```
protobuf==3.17.3
```

And:

```bash
!pip install protobuf==4.21.9
!pip install google-cloud-vision
!pip freeze | grep protobuf
```

Yields:

```
protobuf==4.21.9
```

Then:

```py
from google.cloud import vision

vision
```

Seems to be ok:

```
<module 'google.cloud.vision' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/vision/__init__.py'>
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked!

I have to run the cells at one time, instead of one by one(though it was in a correct order)

Answer (score 0):

@DazWilkin

Thank you for the reply!

It did not work out as expected. the last time i tried shows as bellowed:

[screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riif4.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).